# How to use jsp tag for select?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a view model and one of the fields has to be mapped to a dropdown.  I manage to populate the dropdown but i don't know how to specify the selected value.

edituser.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/template/taglibs.jsp"%>
<div class="container">
    <%@ include file="menu.jsp"%>

    <form:form commandName="editForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-width">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit user</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="hidden" type="text" value="${id}" hidden="true" name="id"/>
                <label for="firstName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">First
                    name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName"
                        placeholder="First name" name="firstName" value="${fname}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Last
                    name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName"
                        placeholder="Last name" name="lastName" value="${lname}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Role</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <select name="role" class="form-control">
                        <option value="NONE">Select role</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="role">
                            <option value="${role}">${role}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
                        placeholder="Username" name="username" value="${username}">
                </div>
            </div>          

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword"
                        placeholder="Password" name="password" value="${guid}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Confirm password</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword"
                        placeholder="Password" name="confirmedpassword" value="${guid}">
                </div>
            </div>      

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="http://localhost:8080/Catering/index/users">Cancel</a> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

UsersController

```
@Controller
public class UsersController {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/editUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getEditUserPage(@RequestParam int id, Model model, Authentication authentication) {



        logger.debug("Received request to show edit user page(GET)");   

        model.addAttribute("username", "You are logged in as " + authentication.getPrincipal());

        UserModel user = UserDataAccess.getUserById(id);

        model.addAttribute("id", user.getId());
        model.addAttribute("fname", user.getFirstName());
        model.addAttribute("lname", user.getLastName());
        model.addAttribute("role", user.getRole());
        model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("guid", guid);
        model.addAttribute("editForm", new UserViewModel());

        return "edituser";
    }
}
```

UserViewModel

```
public class UserViewModel {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String confirmedpassword;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like (not tested)

```
<select name="role" class="form-control">
    <option value="NONE">Select role</option>
    <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="curRole">
       <c:choose>
           <c:when test="${curRole eq role}">
               <option selected="selected">${role}</option>
           </c:when>
           <c:otherwise>
               <option>${role}</option>
           </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

You also must add a Collection in your controller, representing the list of all roles. I cannot see it from your code.

I suggest you to take a look at `spring-form.tld` facilities, in your particular case: select tags: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.select

Here you can find a simple example on how using `spring:form` tag: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/